# Why is intellisense acting so wierd

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After using visual studio 2010 intellisense broke on me and now in visual studio 2013 its doing the following :

[image: intellisense doesn't know return?]

After a few seconds in my project and/or a few line's later it will randomly do this, and not only with return but also with every variable / function / class and sometimes even in a middle of a string.

Closing the tab and opening it agian does work but it will crash visual studio when I save the project.

Is there a way to fix intellisense so I can use it for more then a few seconds?

Comment: Clearly it is still broken.  You need to get your machine stable again.  Start by disabling add-ins.

Comment: You mean the OS or the visual studio install? Because both of them are pretty clean installs.

Comment: Any Visual Studio add-ins installed? Resharper, Code Rush, Roslyn CTP?

Comment: The only add-on I did install was NuGet. But I don't see a problem there.

Comment: If you don't mind a release candidate, there's an Update 1 RC for Visual Studio 2013. Don't know if it would solve that problem, however: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41204

Comment: Updating to the RC fixed the problem for the most part. It still bugs out now and then.

Comment: You may want to check Microsoft Connect to see if it's a reported problem.  They can't fix it if they don't know about it.

Comment: After a day of not having the problems its back agian. And nothing has changed. Didn't reboot my system or visual studio but the problem is back agian. @MetalMikester I always send my crash reports and report the problems I find, so I hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: We should be moving to VS 2013 in the next few weeks (if the Preventers of Information Services let us), so hopefully it will be fixed by then, or it just won't happen to us.  I've used it a bit at home and didn't notice any problems, but haven't used it enough to "prove" anything. Also I was using C# and you're using VB, so the bug could be in the VB Intellisense, rather than be a VS-wide problem (i.e. in all supported languages).

Comment: After a few days of usage the bug returns. It triggers when I save a file. To fix it I need to restart VS2013.

Comment: @RikPabbruwee That is a weird problem. You probably will want to report that to MS... crash reports and statistics I would assume that would be mostly *crashes* not just anytime someone misspells something it sends a report to MS. It seems to me that you have a paid version so you might be able to call them if you are not moved to a newer version in a week or so.